# How do I find the last value of a randomly generated int in c#?

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to find both last positions of X and Y of my player in a .NET Core console application.

Every time I press W, A, S or D, it randomly generates positions (A and D for X values, W and S for Y values) in a map 1000px by 1000px. The problem is when every time it says the last values, only Y value is correct and X is still random.

How do I find the last value of a randomly generated int **(for both X and Y values)** in c#?

```
do
            {             
                targetPos = Console.ReadKey(true);

                if (targetPos.Key != ConsoleKey.Q)
                {
                    playerX = r.Next(0, 1000);
                    playerY = r.Next(0, 1000);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                switch (targetPos.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.D:
                        playerX++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Right - Position X: {0} ", playerX);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.A:
                        playerX--;
                        Console.WriteLine("Left - Position X: {0} ", playerX);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.S:
                        playerY--;
                        Console.WriteLine("Down - Position Y: {0} ", playerY);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.W:
                        playerY++;
                        Console.WriteLine("Up - Position Y: {0} ", playerY);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.Q:
                        Console.WriteLine("\nLast Position X: {0}", playerX);
                        Console.WriteLine("\nLast Position Y: {0}", playerY);
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(targetPos.Key.ToString());
            } while (targetPos.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what functionality you actually expect. Can you give an example of expected in- and output?

Comment: Yes sure. I need to create an algorithm that moves a character's position frame by frame from the position (0,0) to a target random position in a map with 1000px x 1000px.

This is the output in console: https://i.imgur.com/RMJveza.png

Comment: What I wanted is something like this: https://i.imgur.com/e1GjG1q.png

Comment: Your problem is that every keypress thay is not `Q` completely new random values for both `playerx` and `playerY` are generated. Where it seems you only want to randomly generate the corresponding position (So `playerX` when `A` or `D` is pressed and `playerY` when `W` or `S` is pressed) so remove the block that runs when `targetPos.Key != ConsoleKey.Q` and add the correct random generation lines inside the corresponding keys in your `switch`

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Because every time you press a key except Q, both x and y get random. I guess what you want is when press A or D random the x position, when press W or S random the y position, so the code should be:

```
switch (targetPos.Key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.D:
    case ConsoleKey.A:
        playerX = r.Next(0, 1000);
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.W:
    case ConsoleKey.S:
        playerY = r.Next(0, 1000);
        break;
}
```